# Expression blend like functionality in wpf

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I got a canvas which has many uiElements as its children.
When i get the xaml and paste it in Expression blend it displays it well.
Now when i select a path in blend and resize it by dragging the height of it grows successfully increasing the width and the rest of the coordinates are automatically calculated.
I need to give this kind of functionality to my users for the elements on my canvas.
Just wondering if any one has any suggestions or links which can help me.
Thanks
N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at the [Adorner Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737%28VS.85%29.aspx) of WPF. That article gives an overview and is a good place to get started.

[Here](http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!144.entry) is an Adorner sample that probably does what you want.